# Azure web app showing 403

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting an interesting problem that has only started today.

I successfully set up my azure site and have been using it without any issues. I was communicating with it successfully around 10:30am today.

However, when I went to check on it at around 1pm I saw that the tile for my webapp had "deleted" written over it:

[image]

When I try to connect to it I'm getting this error message:

"Error 403 - This web app is stopped.

The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does not accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it again soon."

I am also unable to view any information on the website within the azure portal. For example, if I go to the properties blade I am greeted with "error loading tile".

I have tried creating a new web app, however it was in the same state the moment I created it.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above all of the ftp information that is normally present is missing and my inability to load the properties blade. What makes this even more strange is that I can still ftp to it, as shown here:
[image]

I am using the free shared plan for this server and have already tried restarting the site from within the azure ui.

**FIXED (KIND OF)**

I managed to fix the issue by finally upgrading my account. Creating a new web app using the new subscription and setting it to use the free server. I then just copied the files from the old ftp location to the new one.

Thank you for the responses.

Comment: I'm missing the 'site' directory in your FTP listing. That's where the site should normally be. What is the physical path for the root application? Usually it's `site\wwwroot`.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was covered up by the callander in the screenshot. It was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

403 is returned mainly when you reach the quota limits. I guess you have been using the **Free Pricing Tier** for this web app.

Comment: This is pretty much what I expected and this would also explain why spinning up a new one fixed the issue.

I did try hard to find out if this was the case on the Azure page, but the UI doesn't make finding it easy; I couldn't actually find it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by finally upgrading my account. Creating a new web app using the new subscription and setting it to use the free server. I then just copied the files from the old ftp location to the new one.

This isn't really a fix, it's a workaround. But it's got me working again.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you have your DreamSpark subscription shared with someone else ? could they have deleted your site without your notice ?**

The UI experience you are seeing is showing that your site has been deleted and now you cannot access the site. Please check if the site was deleted due to user action.

Comment: I don't share this with anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

This error has many reasons, maybe:

1. Set incoming client certificate off. More details [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/403-error-code-on-azure/70770/5)
2. Quota limits is reached. [@Sajad Deyargaroo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603186/1027102)
3. The website is not stopped but you still get the error, check [Azure App Service Ip Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) Azure Portal > Your App Service > Networking > Access Restrictions
4. Check the web.config for any ip or domain restrictions. IIS config [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/)